# UITableView not loading data

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

My data is not loading in my `UITableView` and I'm not sure why, as far as I can tell I've done everything by the book.

I created a `TableView` and a `TableViewCell` in storyboard, added an image and three labels.

Structure is: `ViewController` > `TableView` > `TableViewCell` > `Image`, Labels

- My main VC is connected to its ViewController.class
- My `TableViewCell` is connected to its `TableViewCell.class`
- I have an identifyer and linked it up, as per code below
- I linked all the outlets

It's not even loading my `NIB`, on account that I'm not getting any output in the output screen?

```
import UIKit

class MyCell: UITableViewCell, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var cellTitle: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var cellDate: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var cellDescription: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var cellImage: UIImageView!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    print ("Did Load")

    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self

}
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 7
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "myCellID", for: indexPath)
    return cell

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 70
}

}
```

Comment: Why is this code in your `UITableViewCell` class? Should it not be in a `ViewController` class?

Comment: Where do you call tableView.reloadData()?

Comment: @Hodson It was originally, but then I received the error "Outlets cannot be connected to repeating content" and the solution to that was apparently to move the class over on its own.

Comment: @J.Doe I thought that is only for updating the data, where does it need to go?

Comment: @Brewski I update some code :D

Comment: @Brewski Thanks for accepting answer, FYI I added some more code to get you going!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import UIKit

class MyCell: UITableViewCell{ //<-- make sure your cell has this class and connect the outlets

@IBOutlet weak var cellTitle: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var cellDate: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var cellDescription: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView! //<-- what is this doing here?? remove this
@IBOutlet weak var cellImage: UIImageView!

}

class myViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

class Cell{
let title: String
//do this for every UIView in your cell
init(title: String //continue...){
self.title = title
//continue
}
}
var cells = [Cell]()

@IBOutlet weak var myTableView //<-- set here the outlet
override func viewDidLoad() {

    print ("Did Load")
    cells.append(Cell(//initialize))
    myTableView.delegate = self
    myTableView.dataSource = self
    myTableView.reloadData()

}
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 7
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "myCellID", for: indexPath) as! MyCell //<-- ADDED
    cell.cellTitle = cells[indexPath.row].title
    //continue
    return cell

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 70
}
```

Comment: Hi @J. Doe unfortunately I'm getting an error with `cell.cellTitle = cells[indexPath.row].title` **UITableViewCell has no memeber cellTitle** I've tried a few different syntax options but I'm still receiving the same error.

Comment: In your UITableViewCell class, it is called "MyCell" in the example I used, I defined a variable called "cellTitle" (the outlet). Use the name for the outlet you created there.

Comment: @Brewski I made a small change in the code above, search for "ADDED".

Answer (score 1):

all delegate and datasource method of tableview
**[**func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int,

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int,

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell,

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat**]**

must in viewcontroller and not in tableviewcell.

Answer (score 1):

Setting the delegate and data source should be in a view controller. The tableView outlet and all delegate and data source methods should also be in a view controller. try to create a configure cell method in your cell class where you set the data you are going to use to update the UI objects in your in your cell content view and create the cell - type cast as your custom class - in cell for row at method in view controller class.

Answer (score 0):

```
class is MyCell : UITableViewCell
```

but you say Structure is: ViewController > TableView > TableViewCell > Image, Labels.

you should add you tableview in ViewController.

Comment: I had it in there originally, but then I received the error "Outlets cannot be connected to repeating content" and the solution that I found here on StackOverflow was to move the class over on its own like I did.

Comment: It's my pleasure to help you

Answer (score 0):

You need to register the table cell class or nib to the tableview.  Verify that if you have done this or not.